# How to customize FlowTextView for RTL?

Tags: java, android, textview, direction

I'm using "Flow Text View" to wrap my text around a picture.

But them problem is, I'm using Persian language so I have to set text direction to "RTL" but have no idea how to do it for the [Flow Text View](https://github.com/deano2390/FlowTextView).

Here is a picture of how my texts get while direction is LTR...

[image: Problem with ltr]

I hope to help me how to set direction to rtl, I will provide any code you need and I will answer immediately.

Comment: I vote +1 to counter foreign language haters

Comment: Are you using this library https://github.com/deano2390/FlowTextView ?

Comment: you are the true man @AlexanderFarber thank you so much man